# How can I set default width and height in images in the TinyMCE?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm looking to establish a default value for uploaded images within TinyMCE, specifically in this section labeled "Image":

[image: widthandheight]

Here's the code I'm currently using:

```
tinymce.init({
            selector: "#documento_modelo_conteudo",
            plugins: 'autolink charmap codesample emoticons image image link lists media searchreplace table visualblocks wordcount code',
            toolbar: 'undo redo | blocks fontfamily fontsize | bold italic underline strikethrough | image | image | align lineheight | numlist bullist indent outdent | emoticons charmap | removeformat | code',
            image_title: true,
            automatic_uploads: true,
            file_picker_types: 'image',
            file_picker_callback: function (cb, value, meta) {
              var input = document.createElement('input');
              input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
              input.setAttribute('accept', 'image/*');
              input.onchange = function () {
                var file = this.files[0];
          
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function () {
                  var id = 'blobid' + (new Date()).getTime();
                  var blobCache =  tinymce.activeEditor.editorUpload.blobCache;
                  var base64 = reader.result.split(',')[1];
                  var blobInfo = blobCache.create(id, file, base64);
                  blobCache.add(blobInfo);
          
                  cb(blobInfo.blobUri(), { title: file.name });
                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
              };
          
              input.click();
            },
            content_style: 'body { font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px }',
            setup: function(editor) {
              editor.on('init', function() {
                var spans = editor.dom.select("span");
                for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
                  var span = spans[i];
                  observeFieldDeletion(span.className);
                }
              });
            }
          });
```

My objective is to ensure that the image remains within the dimensions of an A4 sheet. Could someone provide assistance with achieving this?